# Alarm is not repeating

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

Here is my code for triggering alarm

```
public void startAlarmp(){

    int hour=10;
    int minute=30;

    Intent alarmIntent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntentp = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 234324243, alarmIntent2, 0);
    alertmanagerp = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alertmanagerp.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,c1.getTimeInMillis(),24*60*60*1000,pendingIntentp);
}
```

and here is my code for AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //my stuff
}
```

it will trigger only first time
after that it is not repeating

and got following error on repeating

```
D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
```

Comment: Please post full output of the logcat error.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the pending intent's flag to 0. Try to change that to `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.

```
pendingIntentp = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 234324243, alarmIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Edit. 
Try this:

```
public void startAlarmp(){

    int hour=10;
    int minute=30;

    Intent alarmIntent2 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntentp = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(YourActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent2, 0);
    alertmanagerp = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alertmanagerp.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 2*60*1000,pendingIntentp);
}
```

Comment: Did you reduce the `intervalMillis` (24*60*60*1000) for testing, right?

Comment: I have modified your code a little bit, check it please. If goes well, then you should modify to your needs step by step.

Comment: Which API level are using?

Comment: Could you post your entire broadcast receiver?

Comment: Actually code is about 300 line and i comment those line and simply put TOAST message and it works fine.

Comment: But you are logging out something right in the beginning of the `onReceive`, right? (only for testing)

Comment: So the alarm is repeating fine when you have only a Toast in your `onReceive` ?

Comment: yes
will you please give me your mail id?
so i will mail my receiver side code...

Comment: So regarding to your latest comment, your alarm manager works fine. Your problem is in your `BroadcastReceiver`. Please post an another question with that problem, here on Stackoverflow.